# C# WPF Multiple Xaml implicit style's selection

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Is there a way of selecting which implicit style is used with in app.xaml of a Wpf project?

I am using a nuget package which contains some control styles. Inside the package the base styles are overridden to set a font and no x:key is specified so they implicitly apply it to the specified controls:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
```

I want to apply the nuget styles to all in my project in the app.xaml like:

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource NugetLabel}"/>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource NugetButton}"/>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Nuget.UI.Wpf;Component/Styles/NugetStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

However when I try and do this the controls do not change to the style as expected. I believe this is due to the implicit style in the merged dictionary is overriding my own implicit style.

Is there a way of selecting which implicit style is used?

I have pulled the source code from the nuget package and commentated out the implicit casting and then everything works as expected

Comment: You would have to remove those entries. Application.Current.Resources.Remove().  The key for a default control style is the Type of that control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your styles to a dictionary that is merged after the imported one:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Nuget.UI.Wpf;Component/Styles/NugetStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource NugetLabel}"/>
                <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource NugetButton}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I also tried putting the Styles in the same resource dictionary as the nuget package

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Are you saying that your styles are not applied?

Comment: Yes the styles did not apply

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample of your issue including a `Button` or `Label` that you expect to be styled.